# Executing some function when the state of a variable changes?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am trying to make a function in my app that is supposed to update the status of my hue lamps when the states of one of them changed.

For now, i have done this :

```
async.waterfall([
function getLightsId(callback) {
    args = {
        path: {
            "username": "webjeremie"
        }
    };

    client.registerMethod("getLightState", "http://hue.jeremieledieu.fr/api/${username}/lights/", "GET");

    client.methods.getLightState(args, function (data, response) {
        var ids = [];
        for (key in data) {
            ids.push(key);
        }
        callback(null, ids);
    });
},
function getLightsState(ids, callback) {
    var lightsState = new Object();
    async.reduce(ids, {}, function(lightsState, id, rcallback) {
      getLightState(id, function(state) {
        lightsState[id] = state;
        rcallback(null, lightsState);
        });
    }, callback);
},


], function (err, currentState) {

        io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
            socket.emit('updateLightsState', currentState);
            previousState = currentState;
        });
});
```

This get me the states of all the lamps in the `currenState` but im stuck at how should i constantly compare  the previous state with the current state, and only emit when the currentState != previousState

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you a suggestion.

Set a value to a variable.

```
var origVal = "Original";
var yourVariable = "Original";

setInterval(function(){
   if(yourVariable !== origVal){
     // do something.
   }
},1000)
```

Comment: Thanks, it was as simple as this :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [answer #1180790](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1760159/1180790)

I think, [object.watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) will make the work here.

Comment: At linked answer, you can find linked Eli Grey`s [implementation](https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583) to work on all major browsers.